# Python Polars Rolling Count

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, rolling-computation, python-polars

There are some known rolling functions in polars, namely rolling_mean(), rolling_apply() and rolling_max(). However, if I would like to get a count on the number of occurrence of a value in each window, how should that be done?

Let's say we now have a LazyFrame:

```
df = pl.LazyFrame({"Date": ["2023-01-01", "2023-01-02", "2023-01-03", "2023-01-05", "2023-01-10", "2023-01-11", "2023-01-12"], "Pattern": [True, True, False, True, False, False, True]})
┌────────────┬─────────┐
│ Date       ┆ Pattern │
│ ---        ┆ ---     │
│ str        ┆ bool    │
╞════════════╪═════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 ┆ true    │
│ 2023-01-02 ┆ true    │
│ 2023-01-03 ┆ false   │
│ 2023-01-05 ┆ true    │
│ 2023-01-10 ┆ false   │
│ 2023-01-11 ┆ false   │
│ 2023-01-12 ┆ true    │
└────────────┴─────────┘
```

And the desired out come, for n = 3 and pattern = True, would be:

```
┌────────────┬─────────┐
│ Date       ┆ Count   │
│ ---        ┆ ---     │
│ str        ┆ int     │
╞════════════╪═════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 ┆ null    │
│ 2023-01-02 ┆ null    │
│ 2023-01-03 ┆ 2       │
│ 2023-01-05 ┆ 2       │
│ 2023-01-10 ┆ 1       │
│ 2023-01-11 ┆ 1       │
│ 2023-01-12 ┆ 1       │
└────────────┴─────────┘
```

I have tried using rolling_sum() over the column Pattern, yet since my column is of Boolean type, using such functions would only yield an error.

In pandas, this can be achieved by:

```
df["Pattern"].apply(lambda x: x == True).rolling(3, min_periods = 0).sum()
```

What is the proper way of doing it with polars? and, how can I generalise the solution to columns other than the True value of Boolean, for example, False and categorical data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried using rolling_sum() over the column Pattern, yet since my column is of Boolean type, using such functions would only yield an error.

You can use `rolling_sum`, you just need to first cast the boolean expression to a numeric type using [`Expr.cast`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cast.html#polars.Expr.cast) (`False` values are converted to `0` and `True` values to `1`).

```
n = 3
pattern_value = True

res = df.with_columns(
    (pl.col('Pattern') == pattern_value).cast(pl.UInt8).rolling_sum(window_size=n)
)
```

For `pattern_value = True` using `(pl.col('Pattern') == pattern_value)` is redundant, you can just use `pl.col('Pattern').cast(pl.UInt8)`.

Output:

```
>>> res

shape: (7, 2)
┌────────────┬─────────┐
│ Date       ┆ Pattern │
│ ---        ┆ ---     │
│ str        ┆ u8      │
╞════════════╪═════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 ┆ null    │
│ 2023-01-02 ┆ null    │
│ 2023-01-03 ┆ 2       │
│ 2023-01-05 ┆ 2       │
│ 2023-01-10 ┆ 1       │
│ 2023-01-11 ┆ 1       │
│ 2023-01-12 ┆ 1       │
└────────────┴─────────┘
```

> In pandas, this can be achieved by:
>
> ```py
> df["Pattern"].apply(lambda x: x == True).rolling(3, min_periods = 0).sum()
> ```

Note that using `min_periods = 0` does not produce the output mentioned. The [`Expr.rolling_sum`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rolling_sum.html) method also accepts the `min_periods` parameter if you want (which defaults to the window size as well). For instance

```py
>>> df.with_columns(
    pl.col('Pattern').cast(pl.UInt8).rolling_sum(window_size=3, min_periods=0)
)

shape: (7, 2)
┌────────────┬─────────┐
│ Date       ┆ Pattern │
│ ---        ┆ ---     │
│ str        ┆ u8      │
╞════════════╪═════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 ┆ 1       │
│ 2023-01-02 ┆ 2       │
│ 2023-01-03 ┆ 2       │
│ 2023-01-05 ┆ 2       │
│ 2023-01-10 ┆ 1       │
│ 2023-01-11 ┆ 1       │
│ 2023-01-12 ┆ 1       │
└────────────┴─────────┘
```